# compare two variables ignoring specified string

Tags: bash, awk, yaml

I am trying to compare two list of IP address space set as separate variables but one of the lists has additional IP range that I'd like to skip in comparison. How can I skip it? `grep` apparently can skip the whole line containing the string, `tr` removes all character occurrences.
I am downloading the fresh IP ranges:

```
wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4 && wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
```

then set it as first variable:

```
L1=$(awk '{printf fmt,$1}' fmt="%s\n" ips-v4 ips-v6 | paste -sd, -)
```

then from the existing YAML file I am setting second variable:

```
L2=$(yq -r .controller.config.proxy-real-ip-cidr yaml.yaml)
```

The L2 has additional string/IP range that I'd like to skip in comparison: `1.2.3.0/32`
Later I am going to send an email if there is a difference between both (except the ignored range)

L1 output:

```
echo "$L1"                                                         
173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/13,104.24.0.0/14,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22,2400:cb00::/32,2606:4700::/32,2803:f800::/32,2405:b500::/32,2405:8100::/32,2a06:98c0::/29,2c0f:f248::/32
```

L2 output:

```
echo "$L2"
173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22,2400:cb00::/32,2606:4700::/32,2803:f800::/32,2405:b500::/32,2405:8100::/32,2a06:98c0::/29,2c0f:f248::/32,1.2.3.0/32
```

Comment: Note that the answers you have so far are based on input which is in turn output of some other tools you're running on the input files when that intermediate step may not be useful, hence @triplee's request to show us the input files so we can best help you.

Comment: Also clarify if the same IPs in different orders across the 2 inputs should be considered differences or not, include such cases in your [mcve], and be sure to add the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` (stream editor) for that task:

```
╰─$ foo="asdftestASDF"      

╰─$ echo "$foo"                             
asdftestASDF

╰─$ echo "$foo" | sed 's/test/bar/'
asdfbarASDF
```

```
╰─$ echo "$L2" | sed -E 's/\,1\.2\.3\.0\/32//'
173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22,2400:cb00::/32,2606:4700::/32,2803:f800::/32,2405:b500::/32,2405:8100::/32,2a06:98c0::/29,2c0f:f248::/32
```

Note that I am escaping dots `.` and slash `/` to avoid them being interpreted as a special symbol in regex or sed.
You could go without escaping the dots, but as `.` in regex matches any character, this could lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ diff <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$L1"|sort) <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$L2"|sort) | \
  awk '/^< /{print "L1 ONLY >>>",$2} 
       /^> /{if($2 != "1.2.3.0/32") print "L2 ONLY >>>",$2}'
L1 ONLY >>> 104.16.0.0/13
L1 ONLY >>> 104.24.0.0/14
L2 ONLY >>> 104.16.0.0/12
```

---

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    exclude_arr["1.2.3.0/32"]
  }
  FNR==NR{ l1[$0]; next }
  { l2[$0] }
  END{
    for (i in l1)
        if (i in l2 == 0 ) print "L1 ONLY >>>", i
    for (i in l2)
        if (i in l1 == 0 && i in exclude_arr == 0) print "L2 ONLY >>>", i
 }
 ' <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$L1") <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$L2")

L1 ONLY >>> 104.16.0.0/13
L1 ONLY >>> 104.24.0.0/14
L2 ONLY >>> 104.16.0.0/12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need, no intermediate variables or other commands required, just 1 call to any awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    NR==FNR {
        sub(/\n$/,"")
        if ( $0 != "1.2.3.0/32" ) {
            local[$0]
        }
        next
    }
    $0 in local{
        print "BOTH:", $0
        delete local[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        print "REMOTE:", $0
    }
    END {
        for ( ip in local ) {
            print "LOCAL:", ip
        }
    }
' RS=','  <(yq -r .controller.config.proxy-real-ip-cidr yaml.yaml) \
  RS='\n' <(wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4) <(wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6)
```

but it's an untested guess. Change "local" and "remote" terms to whatever is more appropriate.